# Setting "due date" reminders in Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-calendar-api, alarm

I've had a glance round the forums and can't see this answered anywhere thus far - I have a google sheets doc that is being populated by google forms being filled in and submitted. One of the fields on this form is a "due date" by which to complete the task being logged on the form. Is there a way to synch this due date with google calendar, so that a calendar-style reminder/alert pops up when the due date is close (like I get my 10min reminder for each meeting in my calendar)

Ideally what I'm after, is being able to set this in the spreadsheet that my google form populates to, and then never having to worry about it again...

Is this doable, or am I expecting too much from google?

Thank you!

Ruth

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. The question is barely related to programming. Please take the [tour], checkout [ask] and the Google Apps Script guide regarding [how to extend Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets)

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at Zapier. This is a free service I use for creating calendar events from Sheets. [Here](https://zapier.com/zapbook/zaps/138/create-google-calendar-events-from-new-spreadsheet-rows/) is the specific Zap I am referring to.